# Update current navigation without getting access denied error

Tags: permissions, 2016, navigation, managed-navigation, current-navigation

Using native SharePoint 2016. user can access the page.

> /AreaNavigationSettings.aspx

After the user changes the navigation and then click 'OK' it shows the "AccessDenied.aspx".

When we go back to the site we can see the updates(navigation done).

So the user has the permission to update the navigation.

When I add the permission :

> "Manage Web Site  -  Grants the ability to perform all administration tasks for the Web site as well as manage content."

The associated permission is:

> Add and Customize Pages  -  Add, change, or delete HTML pages or Web Part Pages, and edit the Web site using a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible editor.

And then user can update navigation without the "AccessDenied.aspx" page.

Comment: After clicking OK, the update happens and the user is redirected to another page. it's possible the access denied happens on that redirect. The query string on the access denied screen should give you a hint where the redirect was intended to go.

Comment: /_layouts/15/AccessDenied.aspx?correlation=d093f79e-1376-90dd-f886-4a3cc5e76179 - only this .

Comment: oh, it's not a publishing page. Sorry. Look in the ULS logs (or have an admin do it) on that correlation id.